# como solucionar error programa.exe dejo de funcionar

Tags: c++

Veran, el objetivo es crear un nuevo elemento para cada uno de los arrays y que tengan la misma posicion en cada uno , a la hora de añadir el elemento en el array de los caracteres(Strings) simplemente me sale el error "programa.exe dejó de funcionar", obviamente el programa se me cierra luego de eso ni idea de cual sera mi error con el codigo me vendria muy bien ayuda de antemano gracias

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;
main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
string nombres[]={"Nutela","Pepito","Dorito","Chupeta","Papitas"};
int codigo[]={5001,4080,1160,1240,4003};
int cantidad[]={7,5,6,4,3};
int precio[]={5,2,4,1,3},i=5;

    i++;
    cout<<"Ingrese el precio: "<< endl;
    cin >> precio[i];
    cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad disponible: "<< endl;
    cin >> cantidad[i];
    cout<<"Ingrese el código que el producto tendrá: "<< endl;
    cin >> codigo[i];
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del producto que desea agregar: "<< endl;
    cin >> nombres[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que estás usando arreglos y estos tienen un tamaño estático.

```
string nombres[]= {"Nutela","Pepito","Dorito","Chupeta","Papitas"};
```

`nombres` es un arreglo de cadenas de 5 elementos. Si se intenta hacer `nombres[5] = "Oreo"` eso produce un error porque la posición 5 del arreglo no existe, los arreglos se cuentan a partir de cero así que las posiciones válidas serían [0,1,2,3,4].

Una forma funcional pero no la mejor sería crear un arreglo con un tamaño más grande para poder agregar más elementos:

```
string nombres[]= {"Nutela","Pepito","Dorito","Chupeta","Papitas","","","","",""};
```

Ahora el arreglo `nombres` tiene una capacidad de 10 elementos así que puede asignar uno en la posición 5 `nombres[5] = "Oreo"`, quedando así:

```
string nombres[]= {"Nutela","Pepito","Dorito","Chupeta","Papitas","Oreo","","","",""};
```

Eso debe hacerse con todos los arreglos, iniciarlos con un tamaño más grande para poder insertar nuevos elementos.

La solución funciona si se sabe por adelantado cuántos elementos contendrá un arreglo o sí los elementos que se insertarán son pocos. Pero si la cantidad de elementos es desconocida es mejor usar otra solución como una estructura de datos llamada vector, la cual puede cambiar de tamaño de forma dinámica conforme se le agregan o remueven elementos.

Ejemplo usando vector para guardar un arreglo de cadenas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
#include <iterator> 
using namespace std;
main(){
    // lista de tipo string
    vector<string> nombres;
    // variable para guardar el nombre desde cin
    string nombre;
    
    // realizar 3 iteraciones
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del producto que desea agregar: "<< endl;
        // leer el nombre
        cin >> nombre;
        // agregar el nombre a la lista
        nombres.push_back(nombre);
        
    }
    
    
    // recorrer la lista y mostrar su contenido
    cout << "contenido de la lista:" << endl;
    for(string n : nombres )
    cout  << n << endl; 

}
```

**Actualización**

Código modificado para usar `vector` en lugar de arreglos estáticos:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    
    /* reemplazo del arreglo estático nombres[] por una estructura vector
      que puede cambiar su tamaño dinámicamente
      string nombres[]={"Nutela","Pepito","Dorito","Chupeta","Papitas"}; */
    
    vector<string> nombres = { "Nutela", "Pepito", "Dorito", "Chupeta", "Papitas" };
    vector<int> codigos = { 5001, 4080, 1160, 1240, 4003 };
    vector<int> cantidades = { 7, 5, 6, 4, 3 };
    vector<int> precios = { 5, 2, 4, 1, 3 };

    // variables para guardar los valores desde el cin
    string nombre;
    int codigo;
    int cantidad;
    int precio;

    cout << "Ingrese el precio: " << endl;
    cin >> precio;
    // insertar el precio al final del vector
    precios.push_back(precio);
    
    cout << "Ingrese la cantidad disponible: " << endl;
    cin >> cantidad;
    cantidades.push_back(cantidad);
    cout << "Ingrese el código que el producto tendrá: " << endl;
    cin >> codigo;
    codigos.push_back(codigo);
    cout << "Ingrese el nombre del producto que desea agregar: " << endl;
    cin >> nombre;
    nombres.push_back(nombre);


    // iterar los vectores para imprimir los resultados
    cout << "Los datos ingresados son:" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < nombres.size(); i++) {
        
        // el vector se puede acceder como un arreglo usando [ i ]
        cout << precios[i] << endl;
        cout << cantidades[i] << endl;
        cout << codigos[i] << endl;
        cout << nombres[i] << endl;
        cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    }
}
```

**Actualización 2 (Opcional)**

Ejemplo de código usando orientación a objetos en el que se usa una clase `Producto` para agrupar los datos individuales y tratarlos como parte de un objeto. (Si aún no se ha estudiado la orientación a objetos puede omitirse ).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// la clase Producto agrupa los datos individuales: precio, cantidad, codigo,nombre
// en un solo objeto, de esa forma se puede usar una colección de Productos
// en lugar de diferentes colecciones para cada datao

class Producto{
    
    public:
        int precio;
        int cantidad;
        int codigo;
        string nombre;

        // constructor con todos los parámetros
        Producto(int precio, int cantidad, int codigo, string nombre){
            this->precio = precio;
            this->cantidad = cantidad;
            this->codigo = codigo;
            this->nombre = nombre;
        }
        // constructor vacío
        Producto(){}
    
};

main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    
    // crear un vector de Productos
    // anteriormente era una colección por cada dato
    // ahora están agrupados dentro un solo objeto
    vector<Producto> productos = { Producto(12,10,123,"Nutela"), Producto(5,10,45,"Oreo") };
    
    // crear un objeto para guardar los datos
    Producto producto;
    
    // ingresar los datos del producto
    
    cout << "Ingrese el precio: " << endl;
    // guardar este dato dentro de producto
    cin >> producto.precio;
  
    cout << "Ingrese la cantidad disponible: " << endl;
    cin >> producto.cantidad;
   
    cout << "Ingrese el código que el producto tendrá: " << endl;
    cin >> producto.codigo;
   
    cout << "Ingrese el nombre del producto que desea agregar: " << endl;
    cin >> producto.nombre;
   
    // insertar el producto al vector
    productos.push_back(producto);


    // iterar los vectores para imprimir los resultados
    cout << "Los datos ingresados son:" << endl;

    for (Producto producto : productos) {
    
      cout << producto.precio << endl;
      cout << producto.cantidad << endl;
      cout << producto.codigo << endl;
      cout << producto.nombre << endl;
      cout << "---------------------" << endl;
  
     }
}
```

Comment: Tambien puedes hacer: `for (string n : nombres)`. Es mas facil de escribir que todo lo de los iteradores, eso que lo haga el compilador.